# Remove rows from one data-frame that exist in another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `DfMaster` and `DfRemove`

`DfMaster` looks like:

```
     Id           Name Building
0  4653     Jane Smith        A
1  3467    Steve Jones        B
2    34        Kim Lee        F
3  4567     John Evans        A 
4  3643   Kevin Franks        S
5   244  Stella Howard        D
```

`DfRemove` looks like:

```
     Id           Name Building
0  4567     John Evans        A 
1   244  Stella Howard        D
```

I would like to remove any records from `DfMaster` if they appear in `DfRemove`.  So my new `DfMaster` in this example would look like:

```
     Id           Name Building
0  4653     Jane Smith        A
1  3467    Steve Jones        B
2    34        Kim Lee        F
3  3643   Kevin Franks        S
```

Where John and Stella have been removed.

I have tried:

```
DfMaster [DfMaster [~DfRemove [id]]]
```

without success.

How can I remove any records from `DfMaster` if they appear in `DfRemove`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there, just do:

```
DfMaster= DfMaster[~DfMaster.Id.isin(DfRemove.Id)]
```

Output:

```
     Id           Name Building
0  4653     Jane Smith        A
1  3467    Steve Jones        B
2    34        Kim Lee        F
3  3643   Kevin Franks        S
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I assuming correctly that `Id` is a unique identifier (i.e. comparing `Id` is sufficient)?

If so, how about this:

```
DfMaster = DfMaster.loc[~DfMaster['Id'].isin(DfRemove['Id'])]
```